# How to refresh canvas by click in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, canvas

I need to clear the canvas by clicking. It's SPA, running Vue CLI v.3.5.0.

`$forceUpdate` doesn't trigger when I click the button but another actions happen (e.g. `console.log`).

```html
<div class="drawing__container">

        <canvas class="drawing-canvas"
                id="canvas"
                :width=canvas_width
                :height=canvas_height
                v-on:mousedown="handleMouseDown"
                v-on:mouseup="handleMouseUp"
                v-on:mousemove="handleMouseMove"></canvas>

        <!-- clear btn -->
        <div class="drawing-clear" @click="clearCanvas">
            <span class="border"></span>
            <span class="border"></span>
            <span class="arrow"><span></span></span>
            <span class="arrow"><span></span></span>
        </div>
        <!-- end -->

        <!-- open modal and share canvas -->
        <span class="drawing-share"
              @click="openModal">Share your love</span>
        <!-- end -->

    </div>
```

```
export default {
        name: "Canvas",
        data: () => ({
            mouse: {
                current: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                },
                previous: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                },
                down: false
            },

            canvas_width: '',
            canvas_height: '',

            modal_state: false
        }),
        computed: {
            currentMouse: function () {
                let c = document.getElementById("canvas");
                let rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();

                return {
                    x: this.mouse.current.x - rect.left,
                    y: this.mouse.current.y - rect.top
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // basic function
            draw() {
                if (this.mouse.down) {

                    let c = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

                    // get width and height of canvas
                    this.canvas_width = document.querySelector('.drawing__container').offsetWidth;
                    this.canvas_height = document.querySelector('.drawing-canvas').offsetHeight;

                    // set canvas setting
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas_width, this.canvas_height);
                    ctx.lineTo(this.currentMouse.x, this.currentMouse.y);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
                    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';

                }
            },

            // set event, if starting drawing
            handleMouseDown(event) {

                this.mouse.down = true;
                this.mouse.current = {
                    x: event.pageX,
                    y: event.pageY
                };

                let c = document.getElementById("canvas");
                let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

                ctx.moveTo(this.currentMouse.x, this.currentMouse.y);

            },

            // set event, if ending drawing
            handleMouseUp() {
                this.mouse.down = false;
            },

            // set event, if moving cursor
            handleMouseMove(event) {

                this.mouse.current = {
                    x: event.pageX,
                    y: event.pageY
                };

                this.draw(event);
            },

            clearCanvas() {
                this.$forceUpdate(this.currentMouse);
            },

            // open modal to share canvas
            openModal() {
                this.$emit('changeStateModal', true);
            }
        },
        ready: function () {
            let c = document.getElementById("canvas");
            let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

The current code should rerender the canvas component, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a method in vue that clears the canvas

so instead of:

```
clearCanvas() {
 this.$forceUpdate(this.currentMouse);
},
```

You need to access your reference of the context and call it like below:

```
clearCanvas () {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
```

You can create a null variable inside of Vue data

```
data: () => ({
    mouse: {
        current: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        previous: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        down: false
    },

    canvas_width: '',
    canvas_height: '',

    modal_state: false,
    context: null
})
```

and then on your ready function set the context to the reference you created for the canvas:

```
ready: function () {
    let c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.context = c.getContext("2d");
    this.context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
    this.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
}
```

I would also suggest to change the ready function to the mounted VueJS lifecycle hook, that basicly fires when your document is ready.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it's working, but now drawing is cached after cleaning. Perhaps this is because of ```computed```?

Comment: Can you share it in a codepen? I think it has nothing to do with computed since the computed method inside just fires when one of the properties changes inside it. I am not sure by just watching the code, but you are callling the draw on the mouseMove, maybe after clearing you should call the draw the first time.

Comment: Ok I think I understood, when you are doing the clearCanvas, the position of your mouse is not 0, 0. Try to reset those, create a method that sets the x and y inside the data to 0

Comment: Please provide me a working example, the current has a lot of errors related to routing and other stuff

Comment: Sorry. Look now, please

Comment: Fixed, the issue was related to the fact that you didn't have a ctx.beginPath(), you need to set a beginPath each time you start drawing a line. Check it now

Comment: @etterwin can you also upvote my answer since it helped you ?

Comment: I cant, sorry. "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
clear() {
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.closePath();
    }
```